# Problem to join the sales_flat_order_item

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a issue when I join the table sales_flat_order_item in my Grid.

What I'm trying to do is add a collumn with the name product ordered, follows the code below.

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=parent_id','method')
        ->join(array('address'=>'sales/order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"', array('postcode', 'city', 'region'))
        ->join(array('sfoi' => 'sales_flat_order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoi.order_id', array('sku'))
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

I created another file for tests.

The code above outputs this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Can't retrieve entity config: sales/sales_flat_order_item' in /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/app/Mage.php:594 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(272): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...') #1 /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(284): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('sales/sales_fla...') #2 /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(488): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable('sales_flat_orde...') #3 /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(569): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getTable('sales_flat_orde...') #4 /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/teste/testando.php(8): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Coll in /var/www/html/homepages/bodebrown.com.br/www/loja/app/Mage.php on line 594
```

**EDIT (I forgot the second code:)**

Ok, I'm also trying this code below,

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=parent_id','method')
        ->join(array('address'=>'sales/order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"', array('postcode', 'city', 'region'))
        ->join( 'sales/order_item', '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', 
            array(
                'name'       => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
            )
          )
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

This one outputs the following result:

[image]

As I'm using the mysql function GROUP_CONCAT, all the name products is returned and only the first order is showed.

Somebody can help me?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what your are trying to do will work without using "group by" or  GROUP_CONCAT because a order my have many items and you can not have duplicate id in a Varien Data Collection.

Take a look at [how to filter sku from renderer in grid?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35465/how-to-filter-sku-from-renderer-in-grid/35475#35475), this seem to be very similar to what you are doing

Comment: I saw this topic, but I can't return the products. The idea is, if a order have 5 products, return 5 lines of the same order with each product name and quantity. When I use the group_concat, the Magento return only the first order with many products. Only the sales_flat_order_item I can't join, the another tables worked perfectly. Sorry, I'm new in Magento's World.

Comment: You may want to using Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection() instead of Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(). Therefore it will return all the items and then join the other table to get addition other info

Comment: Man, thank you very much! This one is working perfectly!